# Read all Request Headers and assign it to a global object

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a webapi in .Net Core 6.0.

```
public class UserDetails
{
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to read the user details from the `httpcontext.Request` and initialize this UserDetails object and store the values in the properties.

And ***use the same object of UserDetails across the application to read the userId and userName***.

All the online articles suggest using ConfigureServices() and add a singleton of the UserDetails class.

But the ***problem is I wont have access to httpContext in the startup.cs/program.cs***.

is there a better way of doing it?

****EDIT1:****

**My Middleware** :

```
public class UserDetailsMiddleWare
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public UserDetailsMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {

            UserDetails userDtls = new UserDetails()
            {
                UserId = httpContext.Request.Headers["userid"],
                UserName = httpContext.Request.Headers["username"]
            };

             await _next(httpContext);
           
        }
    }
```

**My Program.cs** file:

```
services.AddScoped<UserDetails>();
app.UseMiddleware<UserDetailsMiddleWare>();
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    // Get the scoped service from middleware
    var userDetails = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserDetailsMiddleWare>();
    // Populate the user details from the request so that anyone else that resolves this service will have the correct details.
    userDetails.InvokeAsync(context);
    return next(context);
});
```

**My Service:**

```
public class MyService: IMyService
    {
        private readonly IMyGateway _myGateway;
        private UserDetails _details;
        public MyService(IMyGateway myGateway, UserDetails details)
        {
            _myGateway = myGateway;
            _details = details;
        }
        public async Task<string> myMethod()
        {
            string userid =_details.UserId;
            return await _myGateway.GenerateAsync();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worthwhile thinking about the lifetime of objects when reasoning through solving this problem. The reason you don't have an http request at startup is because the server isn't even listening for requests yet. The lifetime of the UserDetails object should match the lifetime of the incoming request (because that's where it's getting the details from). If you made UserDetails a singleton, which is a single instance for *ALL* requests, which user's details would it have? Which request? A singleton is *NOT* what you want in this case.

So breaking the problem down some more, you need to populate the user details object in a place where you have access to the request. The most obvious place for doing that would be in ASP.NET Core middleware.

Now to have that UserDetails object flow to other services, you'd need to make it a [scoped service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#service-lifetimes).

```
services.AddScoped<UserDetails>();

...

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    // Get the scoped service from middleware
    var userDetails = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserDetails>();
    // Populate the user details from the request so that anyone else that resolves this service will have the correct details.
    userDetails.UserId = httpContext.Request.Headers["userid"];
    userDetails.UserName = httpContext.Request.Headers["username"];
    return next(context);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but what is PopulateFromrequest(context) method? is it an inbuilt method or something that needs to be implemented. I have implemented reading the headers in the middleware, however did not understand why we need to have a method in UserDetails class to populate the object

Comment: I have edited the OP to update what I tried based on your suggestions. I still dont get the userdetails value in my service layer.

Comment: Did you add UserDetails as a scoped service? Also you can delete your UserDetailsMiddleWare. This middleware replaces it.